# Webpack output - any way to slice the output to chunks?

Tags: gulp, webpack

I am new to webpack and I love the benefits of using require/import vs. adding multiple **script tags** in the index.html.

However, I wonder whether there is a way to slice a *13MB* output file to chunks so I can have the benefits of the browser's cache like I had with the script-approach.

For instance:

- bundle.react.components.js
- bundle.utils.js
- bundle.redux.reducers.js

That way the loading time of the app will be faster when I make a small change that only affects **bundle.utils.js**.

Cheers,

Comment: Most of your time is spend uploading, so you need to make that faster (compressing files, `rsync`).

Comment: Also why are you uploading `.js` and `.js.gz`? Just upload `.js.gz` and `gunzip` on the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
// your slicing gulp file  
var gulp = require('gulp')  
var webpackStream = require('webpack-stream')  
var path = require('path')  
var webpack = require('webpack')  

gulp.task('slice', function () {  
    return gulp.src('')  
        .pipe(webpackStream({  
            entry: {  
                react_1st: ["react", "react-dom"],  
                utils_2nd: [  
                      "fixed-data-table"  
                    , "./class_1"  
                    , "./class_2"  
                    , "./constants" ],
                remainder_3rd: "./render_component.js" // ReactDOM.render(your_component ...  
           },  
            output: {  
                path: path.join(__dirname, "js"),  
                filename: "bundle.[name].js",  
            },  
            plugins: [  
                new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({  
                    names: ["remainder_3rd", "utils_2nd", "react_1st"],  
                    minChunks: Infinity  
                }),  
            ]  
        }))  
     .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))  
})  

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>  
<script src="bundle.react_1st.js"></script>  
<script src="bundle.utils_2nd.js"></script>  
<script src="bundle.remainder_3rd.js"></script>
```